# DataTables: I receive table.row is not a function, while using meteor's aldeed:tabular

Tags: javascript, meteor

So the DataTables API has a method for parent/child. My goal is to try to turn this into the meteor way of doing this as much as possible.
Here's the link to the webpage -> 
https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

So far the only thing I was able to just add a circle with the green + plus sign. Here's a screen shot->
http://postimg.org/image/l48bfikjf/

Since I'm using meteor things might be a little different, so I'm getting errors on the click event, basically i'm getting table undefined eventhough I defined it.
Here's a gist of the meteor code that i'm trying to turn into datatables parent/child method->

```js
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Full name:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.extn+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extra info:</td>'+
            '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}

  var Tabular = null;

  if (Package['nicolaslopezj:tabular-materialize']) {
      Tabular = Package['nicolaslopezj:tabular-materialize'].Tabular;
  }

  if (Package['aldeed:tabular']) {
      Tabular = Package['aldeed:tabular'].Tabular;
  }

  if (!Tabular) {
    throw new Meteor.Error('orion', 'You must install tabular to use this package');
  }

var table = orion.pages.tabular = new Tabular.Table({
    name: 'PagesIndex',
    collection: orion.pages.collection,
    order: [[1, "desc"]],
    // autoWidth: false,
    columns: [
      {
        className:      'details-control',
        orderable:      false,
        data:           null,
        defaultContent: ''
      }, 
      { data: 'title', title: i18n('pages.schema.title')},
      { data: 'url', title: i18n('pages.schema.url'), render: function(val, type, doc) { return '<a href="' + RouterLayer.pathFor('page', doc) + '">' + RouterLayer.pathFor('page', doc) + '</a>'; } },
      { data: 'position', title: 'Order',
          render: function( val, type, doc) {
            return '<input data-id="' + doc._id + '" type="number" value="' + val + '" class="order-pages">'
          }
      }, 
      { data: 'actions', orderable: false, title: 'Actions',
          render: function (val,type,doc){
            return '<a href="' + Router.path('pages.update', doc) +'" class="btn waves-effect waves-light light-blue accent-4 user-btn-action">Edit</a>'
          },
         tmpl: Meteor.isClient && Template.actionBtns
      }
    ]
  });

Template.orionMaterializePagesIndex.onRendered(function(){
  $('.table').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
  
    console.log(table);
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row( tr );

    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    }
    else {
        // Open this row
        row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
  });
});
```

Maybe one of the seasoned developers can debug the problem I'm having with erros on the click event on the green circle ?

Comment: As I recall, it's important when using Datatables to be explicit about `<thead>` and `<tbody>` when defining the table.  Be mindful of that.

Comment: Right, but doesn't Meteor-Tabular already define that when I integrate it into my html with {{> tabular }}